# MarkLogic - Can we configure scheduled backup on Azure Blob

Tags: azure, backup, marklogic, azure-blob-storage

We want to configure schedule backup for database.

We have set storage account and access key for Azure Blob in security-> Credentials for Azure.

In backup directory, when enter azure://containName
This container name is exist in given storage account.

In response it says
The directory azure://backup/ does not exist on host ml01. Would you like to try and create it?

Can anybody please help me to configure?

Comment: In MarkLogic on Azure documentation, it says " We do support Azure blob storage for backup " https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/azure.pdf, so i need to know how to ?
Can somebody please reply?

Comment: Can somebody from MarkLogic help me to configure backup directly on Azure Blob?

Comment: Anybody from MarkLogic support help me to resolve this please? @Michael Gardner

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to create a work job which backup the data of your MarkLogic Database to Azure Blob Storage and trigger by a time schedule. Right? I do not completely understand what you said, so here just my suggestion below.

I'm not familar with MarkLogic, but I think you can write a script for NodeJS or a Java program to do the backup work, after I read the tag info for [`marklogic`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/marklogic/info) and I see it supports the client API for Node and Java.

As I known, there are three ways normally to deploy it on Azure if you are ready to backup in programming.

1. You can deploy it as a webjob with a cron expression to trigger the backup work, please refer to the offical document [`Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create).
2. You can deploy it as a Web API on Azure by using the service like WebApp, and use [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-get-started-portal) to trigger it.
3. You can deploy it as an Azure Function and trigger it with timer trigger, please refer to the offical document [`Create a function in Azure that is triggered by a timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function).

Ofcourse, there are other services can help to realize your needs. I don't know what the best for you is. If you have any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your reply, in MarkLogic, there is option to schedule backup and you can provide path, so we are actually looking whether there is option to configure Azure blob for database backup or not.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into similar issue and was able to resolve it.

Create something side your container within a folder. so your structure should look like this

azure://containername/folder

I just was able to resolve my issue by doing that.

Comment: Hello Jacob, Thanks for your reply. Still it is asking to create i.e. The directory azure://backup/marklogic does not exist on host host-01. Would you like to try and create it?